# vector unpacking for octave

Tags: matlab, octave, unpack, iterable-unpacking

Octave(/matlab)'s notation for handling multiple return values

```
[a, b] = f(x)
```

suggests that the values returned by f(x) are in a sort of row vector and that Octave supports vector unpacking (like Python's tuple-unpacking).

Yet when I put

```
[a, b] = [1, 2]
```

I get

> error: invalid number of output arguments for constant expression

Does octave support vector-unpacking?

If so, what's the proper notation?

I can't find anything in the documentation

Comment: The square brackets (`[]`) have a slightly different meaning when the right side of the assignment is a function call. What is it that you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I have two vectors (A and B) I want to iterate over simultaneously.
In python I would do

for a,b in zip(A,B):
  //Do some stuff with a and b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have Octave to test, but in MATLAB you can "unpack" cell arrays.

```
x = {1 2};
[x1,x2] = x{:}

x1 =
     1
x2 =
     2
```

You can convert numerical vector to a cell array as `x = num2cell([1 2]);`.

I have to add that this works for MATLAB starting from version 7.0. For earlier version you have to use [DEAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) function.

Comment: That works in Octave as well. Thanks.
It still seems a little wordy for such a common operation