# attempt to assign matlab matrix to an matrix of named variables produces 'too many output arguments' error

Tags: matlab

The matlab function sscanf returns a variable size matrix (or perhaps a cell array?) which can be assigned to a matrix of variable names

```
>> clear all ;
line = '1 2' ;
[a, sz] = sscanf( line, '%d %d' ) ;
```

It appears that the output matrix `a` is a column matrix, which can be transposed to form a 1x2 matrix:

```
b = a' ;
```

I'd like to be able to assign this to an matrix of variable names, like I can do in the preceding sscanf call.  I figured I'd be able to do:

```
[c,d] = b ;
```

but this gives me the error:

```
Too many output arguments.
```

From the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23800927/189270 it looked like I may be able to do this by transforming the matrix `a` into a cell array, however, I don't seem to be able to figure out the right syntax for this:

```
>> num2cell(a)

ans =

    [1]
    [2]

>> [c,d] = num2cell(a)
Error using num2cell
Too many output arguments.

>> [c,d] = num2cell(a')
Error using num2cell
Too many output arguments.

>> [c ; d] = num2cell(a)
 [c ; d] = num2cell(a)
  |
```

I can solve the problem by brute force by assigning to the fields `b`, `c` one at a time indexing into the matrix `a`.  However, I imagine this is a common type of bulk variable assignment (I do this in Mathematica for example), so I wanted to understand what is wrong with my attempts above, and what the correct matlab syntax for this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it correct.  Once you take your numbers and convert them into individual cells in a cell array (through `num2cell`), use [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) to distribute each element in your cell array to your corresponding variables.  As such:

```
%// Your code
line = '1 2' ;
[a, sz] = sscanf( line, '%d %d' ) ;

%// New code!
b = num2cell(a);
[c,d] = deal(b{:});
```

This is what I get after `deal`:

```
c =

     1


d =

     2
```

Comment: thanks.  From the deal docs (example 3), it looks like [c,d] = b{:} also works.