# What is the point of the deal() function in Octave / MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, octave

Some reference code uses the function `deal()` trivially, like

```
[a, b, c] = deal (1,2,3)
```

As described in the documentation ([for Octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/deal.html) and [for MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html)), the function simply copies the inputs to the outputs.  **Why use `deal()` in this case, or even in general?**  I'm trying to learn "more correct" MATLAB/Octave usage, and wondering if I'm missing something significant.  Perhaps, is this usage...

- conventionally stylistic or idiomatic, in place of simple assignment like `a=1, b=2, c=3` or the more arcane list-unpacking of cell-arrays like `[a,b,c] = {1,2,3}{:}`, but even more restricted than Python [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393161/vector-unpacking-for-octave)?
- useful for some more elegant feature -- e.g., "deep" versus "shallow" copy, if such a concept even exists here, if `deal()` were used with complicated/variable arguments?

I also understand single-argument `[a,b,c]=deal(42)` but that's essentially `a=b=c=42`, and `[a,b,c]=deal(x)` assigns `x` to all, not elements-of-`x` to each.

Or perhaps it's ONLY that I'm over-thinking this trivial use of the function.

Comment: It is a totally trivial function, type in `edit deal` and take a look at the code. You do not need deal, I never used it and never missed it.

Comment: I guess you answered your own question. As far as I know, there is no other reason to use `deal()` other than readability. The "deep" vs. "shallow" copy question that you raised is irrelevant here (at least in Octave), because the interpreter is smart enough to detect when `a = b` needs to actually be copied in memory.

Comment: Is there an analogous function in C?

Comment: @BrysonS. -- There is no analogous function in C for a few reasons. The MATLAB `deal` function takes a variety of inputs (scalar, comma-separated list, cell-array, structure-array accessor, ...), so you'd have to do something like [tagged unions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/479266/3562032). Or you could use some wacky variadic stuff or C++. Multiple output values is a problem, so you'd have to return arrays or structs or pointers, ... but this seems far too complicated. What's the application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One really useful way that I occasionally use `deal` is to create anonymous functions that return multiple output arguments. For example,

```
>> f = @(x) deal(x^2,x^3);
>> [a,b] = f(3)
a =
     9
b =
    27
```

**Edit** since people seem to find this pattern potentially useful, do note a quirk, in that you must return the full number of outputs. In particular, you can't use `a = f(3)`, or it will error. To retrieve just a single output, use `[a,~] = f(3)` or `[~,b] = f(3)`. The `~` syntax for suppressing output arguments has been around since about R2007a or so (I'm afraid I can't recall exactly when) - in older versions, you will need to always return both outputs. Hope that may be useful for you.

Comment: Clever indeed, and I don't immediately see any other way of doing that; playing around with a few indexing and cs-list don't seem to work right. That should go on the docs for [anonymous functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Anonymous-Functions.html) or for `deal`!

Comment: Is there something like this in C?

Comment: @BrysonS. -- see my response to your similar comment under the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

First, your named examples work with octave, but not with matlab!

```
octave:1> a=b=c=42
a =                   42
octave:2> [a,b,c] = {1,2,3}{:}
a =                    1
b =                    2
c =                    3


>> a=b=c=42
 a=b=c=42
    |
Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

>> [a,b,c] = {1,2,3}{:}
 [a,b,c] = {1,2,3}{:}
                  |
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

How and when to use `deal()` can not be generalized. It depends on you scripte, your datastructure, what you want to do and how the result should look like etc.

```
>> m=rand(3,3);
>> [a,b,c]=m;
Too many output arguments.

>> [a,b,c]=reshape(m,[],1);
Error using reshape
Too many output arguments.

>> [a,b,c]=deal(reshape(m,[],1));
>>
```

So some functions are designed with nargout = 1 and you can easily distribute the output to sevaral variables in "one line".

And if a functions has more nargouts than 1, it gets interesting

```
>> [x,y,z]=qr(m)

x =

   -0.7004    0.6471   -0.3012
   -0.1144   -0.5183   -0.8475
   -0.7045   -0.5592    0.4370


y =

   -1.3776   -0.7928   -1.2897
         0   -0.6388   -0.0796
         0         0   -0.3499


z =

     1     0     0
     0     0     1
     0     1     0

>> [x,y,z]=deal(qr(m))

x =

   -1.3776   -1.2897   -0.7928
    0.0673   -0.3588   -0.1418
    0.4143   -0.1886    0.6229


y =

   -1.3776   -1.2897   -0.7928
    0.0673   -0.3588   -0.1418
    0.4143   -0.1886    0.6229


z =

   -1.3776   -1.2897   -0.7928
    0.0673   -0.3588   -0.1418
    0.4143   -0.1886    0.6229

>>
```

However, doublicating variables *(e.g. to keep a better overview)* is not so bad as it might be in other languages *(in regard of memory wasting)*. Matlab uses copy on write - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write and http://www.matlabtips.com/copy-on-write/

And - afaik - octave too:

```
octave:1> memory

 Memory used by Octave:   24.4414 MB 
 Physical Memory (RAM): 7586.74 MB 

octave:2> tic, m=rand(10000,10000); toc
Elapsed time is 5.52749 seconds.
octave:3> memory

 Memory used by Octave:   787.531 MB 
 Physical Memory (RAM): 7586.74 MB 

octave:4> tic, n=m; toc
Elapsed time is 4.19617e-05 seconds.
octave:5> memory

 Memory used by Octave:   787.535 MB 
 Physical Memory (RAM): 7586.74 MB 

octave:6> whos
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
        m       10000x10000              800000000  double
        n       10000x10000              800000000  double

Total is 200000000 elements using 1600000000 bytes
```

Comment: On the MAT vs. Oct part: wacky; thanks for the comparison. I got the cell-array-list syntax `[a,b,c,d] = C{:}` from [the MATLAB docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html)... indexing of "anonymous" cell-arrays won't work in MAT...? My Octave was missing memory.m; found [here](https://github.com/markuman/linux/blob/master/octave/memory.m). After the above, I set one element of n as `tic, n(1234,2345)=42; toc` takes ~1sec and then `Memory used by Octave: ...` doubles -- CoW indeed! Thanks for the tips.